# javac PATH and CLASSPATH help

Tags: java

Just learning java. I get the errorjavac is not recognized as an internal or external cmd. In my EV I start it with %PATH% then the C..Prog Files\java\ver\bin. Is this correct? And for classpath I just have same as above except no %PATH% and \jre\bin. I still get the error. Can anyone guide me ? Thanks so much..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first mistake is that `javac` is not in the JRE binary folder, it's in the JDK folder. You don't need to prefix your path with `%PATH%` either. Your path should look something like this:

```
C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Proram Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_06\bin
```

each entry is separated by a semicolon (`;`)

In case you may be configuring it in the wrong place, it is done under **My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables**. Simply append a semicolon and then the path of your JDK's bin folder to the existing line.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect Solution by John, If you are confused with editing the variables, You can try [Path Editor GUI](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor/)

[image]